# Resolution List (OpenCv,Python,Camera)

Tags: python, arrays, list, opencv

Hi I want to test the resolution of my camera. Normally I set this manually ,the resolution (w,h) 320,480 ...

Now i want that the set the list resolution = [(...)] in a loop or better in a **function** that it gives me the each output automatically, so i dont have to write each resolution per hand. i tried a lot but it dont get it.

hope someone can help me

thx!

Code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\opencv\\build\\python\\2.7")
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import time

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

num_frame = 0

resolution = [(320,480),(640,480),(704,680),(960,680),(1280,720),(1440,720),(1920,1080)]

w = 320
h = 480

size = capture.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), capture.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

size_new = capture.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, w),capture.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,h)

print size

start = time.time()

while(True):
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    if num_frame < 60:
        num_frame = num_frame + 1
    else:
        break

total_time = (time.time() - start)
fps = (num_frame / total_time)
print str(num_frame) + ' Frames ' + str(total_time) + ' Sekunden = ' + str(fps) + ' fps'

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Does the current code works fine ? If yes then you simply need to encapsulate the code inside a function and call it inside a for loop while iterating over the list `resolution`

Comment: The Code woks fine! But how can i put it in a function an call it inside a loop? Thats my problem. Can please show me this . Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this by encapsulating the script inside a function and calling it on the resolutions in the list while iterating the list.

Actually the code was pretty fast , so `total_time = (time.time() - start)` was evaluating to zero in some cases and hence giving the error: `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero` on the line `fps = (num_frame / total_time)`, since the total_time was evaluating to 0, so I added `time.sleep(0.001)` to get rid of this error.

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import time

resolution = [(320,480),(640,480),(704,680),(960,680),(1280,720),(1440,720),(1920,1080)]

def change_resolution(w, h):

   capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

   num_frame = 0

   size = capture.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), capture.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

   size_new = capture.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, w),capture.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,h)

   print size

   start = time.time()

   while(True):
       ret, frame = capture.read()
       if num_frame < 60:
           num_frame = num_frame + 1
           time.sleep(0.001)
       else:
           break

   total_time = (time.time() - start)
   fps = (num_frame / total_time)
   print str(num_frame) + ' Frames ' + str(total_time) + ' Sekunden = ' + str(fps) + ' fps' + ' for width: ' + str(w) + ' height: ' + str(h)

   capture.release()
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()


for reso in resolution:
   change_resolution(reso[0], reso[1])
```

**Output:**

```
(0.0, 0.0)
60 Frames 0.0599999427795 Sekunden = 1000.00095368 fps for width: 320 height: 480
(0.0, 0.0)
60 Frames 0.0639998912811 Sekunden = 937.501592564 fps for width: 640 height: 480
(0.0, 0.0)
60 Frames 0.0599999427795 Sekunden = 1000.00095368 fps for width: 704 height: 680
(0.0, 0.0)
60 Frames 0.0599999427795 Sekunden = 1000.00095368 fps for width: 960 height: 680
(0.0, 0.0)
60 Frames 0.0599999427795 Sekunden = 1000.00095368 fps for width: 1280 height: 720
(0.0, 0.0)
60 Frames 0.0599999427795 Sekunden = 1000.00095368 fps for width: 1440 height: 720
(0.0, 0.0)
60 Frames 0.0599999427795 Sekunden = 1000.00095368 fps for width: 1920 height: 1080
```

Comment: what ist change_resolution(reso[0],reso[1]) doin ?  ist reso[0] catchin the w and reso[1] the h ? thank you ZdaR ;-)

Comment: `change_resolution()` is a function in which you can change the values of `w` and `h`, opposite to the previous scenario in which the values of `w` and `h` were constant @Jan, you can accept the answer by marking it with a green tick if that helped you. :)

Comment: where is the green tick ? :-)

Comment: below the arrows on top left side of my side